# How to read rules(definitions) from files in flex?

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I have been creating token definitions in my .l file. Due to large amount to dataset, it is getting little tedious.
Is there any way to **read all words from file** e.g. noun.txt containing all nouns and give all of them a single token.

Basically, I want to automate this part:

```
%%

[\r\n]                  {;return T_QUIT;}
"morning"|"flight"      {return NOUN;}
"I"|"him"                       {return PRO;}
"a"                     {return DET;}
"prefer"|"play"|"love"              {return VERB;}
"Los Angeles"|"ali"|"home"  {return PNOUN;}
"on"|"at"                   {return PRE;}
"exit"      {return T_QUIT;}
"quit"      {return T_QUIT;}

%%
```

Comment: What about a generator producing the flex definitions from the file ? See my answer

Answer (score 1):

*flex* generates code, so you cannot read `noun.txt` at execution time and have them managed directly by *flex* if this is what you expect

Of course you can use *flex* to read an identifier/word (sequence of alpha) and manages the nouns known thanks to `noun.txt` (already read and its content memorized to be used) in a special way into the body part ({...}) associated to the identifier. But in that case the interest to use *flex* is very limited, and you have a problem with the case of "Los Angeles" having a space inside (but may be it is "Los-Angeles" ?)

You can also write a generator producing the flex file from `noun.txt` to have them directly managed by *flex*. This is probably the best way to do if the nous do not have to change at any time. Your *flex* definitions are very simple and easy to generate.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the command

```
sed 's/^/"/; s/$/"|/' noun.txt >> nounrule.txt
```

useful. This basically writes the bulk of the rule for you, you will just have to add the action part at the end.